# Embarrasingly easy question: keep getting Invalid syntax error when trying to invoke the okcmd package

Tags: python-2.7, syntax-error

I am sure that this is a dumb thing I am doing or not doing. I hardly ever use python so I forget.

I am using python 2.7 because that is what the package was written in.

1. In a DOS command window I used the command `pip install okcmd` and it seemed to have worked, although I received the notice that pip is being deprecated.
2. I fired up idle. I got the python shell.
3. I typed `import okcmd`. No error messages, so I assumed it worked.
4. I typed `okcmd`.  I didn't include any arguments so I was expecting some sort of error. Idle responded with `<module 'okcmd' from 'D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\okcmd\__init__.pyc'>`. I interpreted that as a good sign.
5. I then typed `okcmd -u a1 -p a2 -f 'a.txt'`. I used my real username instead of a1 and real password instead of a2, but I get the same result if I use a1 and a2. I received `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`.

Here is a link to the package description: https://github.com/lehrblogger/OkCupid-Message-Downloader

What do I need to do to get the thing to run instead of give me a syntax error? I assume it is me not invoking it correctly rather than the code because no line number was indicated for the invalid syntax. If it is the code I don't need help debugging it - I'll bail on the whole thing.

Thanks

Comment: That line that gives you a syntax error is indeed not valid Python syntax. It looks like it expects you to be able to run the module as a script (maybe the script is separate, I'm not sure). Try running it from the command line instead of in the Python shell.

Comment: That was it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When installed, okcmd adds it's command to the installation Python's Scripts subdirectory.  If that directory is in your path, you can just type `okcmd -u a1 -p a2 -f a.txt` at the command windows prompt.

Otherwise, if Python is installed in `C:\Program Files\Python27`, you can run:

```
"c:\program files\python27\scripts\okcmd" -u a1 -p a2 -f a.txt
```

Comment: That did the trick. Now it runs and crashes, but those are internal errors, likely because the website has changed. I only knew about running from idle, not a dos shell. Thank you very much.